# How to add character in xml element - VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

Below is the XML Node. I am adding nodes like below..

```
<ANNEXURE_A>
<ANNX_A/>
</ANNEXURE_A>
```

But I want it like..

```
<ANNEXURE_A>
    <ANNX_A id="1">
    </ANNX_A>
</ANNEXURE_A>
```

How do I add id = "1" in element.

below is the code I am using:

```
Set nodElement = docXMLDOM.createElement("ANNEXURE_A")
Set docXMLDOM.DocumentElement = nodElement
For i = 1 To 10
    Set nodChild = docXMLDOM.createElement("ANNX_A ID=" & """ & i & """)

    nodElement.appendChild nodChild
Next i
docXMLDOM.Save path

Set docXMLDOM = Nothing
```

But it is throwing error **This may not contain '=' character**. How to I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the attribute independently:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    Set nodChild = docXMLDOM.createElement("ANNX_A")

    nodChild.setAttribute "ID", i

    nodElement.appendChild nodChild
Next i
```

Comment: OK I will get back to you tomorrow as I am travelling..looks fine though. Thanks